# Does resharper make you lazy?

Tags: coding-style, resharper

I've been looking at using resharper and from the reviews I've seen, people who start using it never go back.

I'm wondering if using resharper helps you pick up errors when looking at code without resharper, or does it decrease this ability becaues you get use to relying on resharper to identify problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found that it helps me clean up my code, but I don't think it's an effective crutch.  You might say Intellisense has made me lazy, but not Resharper.

Sadly, I had to disable resharper on my workstation,p though.  It was too damned slow.

Comment: Agreed... Intellisense has made way more lazy than any refactory tool out there.

Answer (score 7):

If anything ReSharper has made me less lazy:

- Simple refactorings like moving a class to a separate file only requires a few keystrokes. Without ReSharper I might postpone these refactorings until later resulting in more "lazy" code.
- You can configure ReSharper to flag unwanted constructs in your code. Without assistance from ReSharper I have to spend more effort making my code consistent. ReSharper helps me avoid sloppy or "lazy" code.
- In general I don't see how being more efficient makes you more lazy.

Also, ReSharper has learned me quite a few details about C# programming I wasn't aware by flagging certain constructs in my code.

Comment: That point Martin made about refactoring cannot be stressed enough. With ReSharper, I find myself thinking more about what I'm trying to accomplish and less about the mechanics of accomplishing it. If anything, I'm more ambitious because of ReSharper, not lazier.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that ReSharper helps me get into good habits, I use better idioms and patterns because it flags them for me.

Answer (score 1):

I used it for the trial period, and found it to be more of a headache than it's worth. Way too slow, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it decreases your ability to do what R#er does without it.
If losing this ability means laziness for you, then yes - R#er makes you lazy.

But it's hard to beat and replace R#er with your skills without losing productivity.
So - what's the point polishing them?

Answer (score 1):

Resharper helps you do the things that developers are meant to do - concentrate on application logic and design. More often than not good design evolves over time and in my opinion your tools should aid you in achieving that design in minimum effort rather than bog you down because of the magnitude of changes that you will have to do.

Resharper with its feature support will always encourage you to do better without taking a hit on productivity. It's like mowing the lawn by hand after you are used to the electric lawn mower.